# Perl 6 multiple global regex or character substitutions

Tags: raku

What is the best style to write multiple character substitutions in Perl6? E.g. I want to replace letters of one alphabet with letters of another alphabet. Suppose my 1st "alphabet" is abcd and my 2nd — efgh, so I want to make substitutions a → e, b → f, c → g, d → h. Using `sed` I would write:

```
$ echo dcba | sed 'y/abcd/efgh/'
hgfe
```

In Perl6, as I understand, I should write something like this:

```
$ echo dcba | perl6 -pe 's:g/a/e/; s:g/b/f/; s:g/c/g/; s:g/d/h/'
hgfe
```

If I take an alphabet of 20-30-40 (or even more) characters, this will be inconvenient. Is there a better way to solve this problem with Perl6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl6 there is a transliteration operator `tr` as in Perl 5. In Perl6, there is also a method form of this operator called [`trans`](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Transliteration):

```
echo dcba | perl6 -pe '$_.=trans(["a".."d"] => ["e".."h"])'
```

**Output**:

```
hgfe
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! What does the `.` in `.=` mean? And am I right that `trans` takes two lists as arguments? Can it take a hash?

Comment: Yes, I've checked, it takes a hash! So, my question is only about `.=`.

Comment: @evb In Perl 6 `=` is a meta operator that can be combined with most infix operators. `a OP= b` is the same as `a = a OP b`. This was made this way so that `+=` and friends weren't special cases anymore. (One of the goals in the design was to remove or extend as many special cases as practicable.)

Comment: @BradGilbert, thanks! I was slow to figure out that `.` for methods is also an infix operator. :)

Comment: Fyi, simplifying yields `echo dcba | perl6 -pe '.=trans: "a".."d" => "e".."h"'` (cuz `.foo` means exactly same as `$_.foo`; `.foo: ...` means exactly same as `.foo(...)`; and apparently the `trans` method does exactly the same thing with `range => range` as its argument as it does with `[range] => [range]`).